# php combobox default selected

Tags: php, mysql, combobox, default

Imagine that:

A field that could be YES or NO -> Active: Yes | Active: No

So, i got a query that returns it for each client.

I want to show the results in a form, and I should be able to edit that and save on BD again.

I can almost do it, but I need that the default value be wich was already saved on BD, and what I have atm seems show the last row or something.

I want that show the current status or be able to change it for (Yes or NO)

It goes like this for the combobox:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM client,sector WHERE client.idClient = '$id' AND sector.idSector=client.Sector_idSector ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

<select name="alterar_sector" id="sectorbox" >
    <?php 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['idSector'].'">'.$row['idSector'].' - '.$row['Nomesec'].'</option>';
    }

    ?>
    </select>

}
```

Dont give importance of info displayed like "sector" or even the query etc..

Resume:

I want that combobox could display the current value as default and give a list of anothers possible values to change.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might have missed the point of the question, but are you asking how you can make a from field appear as being selected?
Simple modify this line:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['idSector'].'">'.$row['idSector'].' - '.$row['Nomesec'].'</option>';
```

To have:

```
echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row['idSector'].'">'.$row['idSector'].' - '.$row['Nomesec'].'</option>';
```

If that is the particular option you want selected...

You might have something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($sectorActive != $row['idSector']) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['idSector'].'">'.$row['idSector'].' - '.$row['Nomesec'].'</option>';
  }else{
    echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row['idSector'].'">'.$row['idSector'].' - '.$row['Nomesec'].'</option>';
  }
}
```

---

Ok, so if you want a select field to have a default value you need to have `selected="selected"` as a paramater value in the `<option>` element. As per your example like this:

```
<select name="gender">
  <option>Male</option>
  <option>Female</option>
  <option selected="selected">Other</option>
  <option>Not Specified</option>
</select>
```

So if you have a query pulling records and you want to make sure you have the right value selected. You need to have a variable that changes with each record - and you need to install some logic in that HTML insert, like this: *(this example will output the same HTML as the example above...)*

```
<?
    $usersGender = 'Other'; // This value should be set via the loop, and from a database value.
?>
<select name="gender">
  <option <?=($usersGender=='Male')?'selected="selected"':''?>>Male</option>
  <option <?=($usersGender=='Female')?'selected="selected"':''?>>Female</option>
  <option <?=($usersGender=='Other')?'selected="selected"':''?>>Other</option>
  <option <?=($usersGender=='Not Specified')?'selected="selected"':''?>>Not Specified</option>
</select>
```

Comment: With that: `echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row['idSector'].'">'.$row['idSector'].' - '.$row['Nomesec'].'</option>';` im getting the last position on row. Or my query is wrong :x

Comment: For each `<select>` element you can only have a single `<option>` as being the *selected* one. The snippet of code you provided is not enough to completely work out what is going on. In my example the variable `$sectorActive` is made up, you need to put your own logic into that if statement.

Comment: The reason the last item is being selected is because every single one of your options is being `selected` - so the very last element is the one that is shown.

Comment: Hi, ty for helping me. Let me try a different aproach. Imagine that i got a field called Gender. My name is a record on DB as Male. Now I got a page with a form and in my <select> shoud appear bu default my current gender and should be able to change it for another.

Comment: Check my edit, I have added as section which hopefully provides some more information :)

Answer (score -1):

THE BEST

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  if ($sectorActive != $row['idSector']) {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['idSector'].'">'.$row['idSector'].' - '.$row['Nomesec'].'</option>';
  }else{
    echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row['idSector'].'">'.$row['idSector'].' - '.$row['Nomesec'].'</option>';
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.